# Is a 1D flag chart possible?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to create a chart similar to

[image]

(the line shapes, colors, flag shape are not important).

Each of the flags represent an `x` value and the x axis boundaries are fixed. This is very similar to a [highchart demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-timeline)  (the round and rectangular flags along the x axis) but it looks like the flags are added (via `options.series.push`) to existing data.

The [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series) mentions however that

> Used alone flag series will make no sense.

Based on the demo, I tried to create a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/e15dtn6o/) by forcing the type to `flags` but it does not render

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  series: [{
    type: 'flags',
    data: [{
      x: 10,
      title: 'hello',
      text: 'say hello'
    }, {
      x: 20,
      title: 'world',
      text: 'say world'
    }, {
      x: 50,
      title: 'bonjour',
      text: 'say bonjour'
    }],
    shape: 'circlepin',
    width: 16
  }]
});
```

**Is there a direct way to create such 1D flag charts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the console for errors you can see that you are getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

I wrapped your `highcharts` builder code in a `function` tag and it loads fine now. See this live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/e15dtn6o/1/).

Comment: Thank you - I was so sure that it does not work that I missed that (obvious) check.

Comment: @WoJ, also note that, even though it is not documented in the API you can set a `y` position. Kind of hacky but works when needed. There are other ways to do this of course (invisible bar/line/scatter points with dataLabels on).

Comment: You comment about  the vertical placement is a very relevant one - I will quickly run into overlapping labels when everything is aligned on a horizontal line. I will probably end up generating `y` values to scatter the labels up and down so that the result is more readable (it would be great if this was possible out of the box). Thanks again.

Comment: @WoJ, if what you want is just label items on some chart you could also do a `scatter` series type and enable `dataLabel`s on them. Lets you do finer placement.